# How to sort out the wrong entries in the most simple way depending on the corresponding line in the other file?

Tags: bash, read

I have two files:

In one I have a list of strings, which need to removed if the corresponding line in the other file contains a string "NOPE". If it contains "YES" it stays there. Note that removing one line might destroy the order. The format is like this:

1.txt:

```
Jimmy
John
Johnson
```

2.txt:

```
YES
NOPE
YES
```

Correct Output:

```
Jimmy
Johnson
```

What's the simplest way to do this for thousands of entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could so something like

```
paste 2.txt 1.txt | awk '$1 == "YES" {print $2}'
```

(for single-word strings) or

```
awk 'NR==FNR && $0=="YES" {i[FNR]; next} FNR in i' 2.txt 1.txt
```